# Dismissing iOS mail app opened from UIDocumentInteractionController removes the presenting ViewController's view in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

I have implemented ***UIDocumentInteractionController*** in my app for showing open in options. It's working fine on iOS8 devices, but in iOS7 when I open my PDF in the mail from options. It opens mail composer when I dismiss the mail composer it also removes a menu button from my view (which is added to the window). I spent my whole day struggling with this issue but could not find any solution. When I open my PDF in other options, there is no issue. The issue is only with mail composer with iOS7. I know ***UIDocumentInterfaceController*** has issue with iOS7. 
 [I found the same issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462710/dismissing-a-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-in-some-cases-will-remove-the-prese) but this is with preview option of a quick look.

Here is my code to open options

```
[self.docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.frame
                                                   inView:self.view
                                                 animated:YES];
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use self.window instead of self.view.

Comment: @IOSDev window in not accessible from self. I have also tried presenting option menu on application's window.

Comment: it can be accessible from self have a look                                                 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Comment: NSString *textToShare = @"Los!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.a.com/"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"index.jpg"];
    
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite, image];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   ];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: It removes menu button  or removes bottom modal view controller?

Comment: @MayankJain, where you placed a mail app dismiss code?

Answer (score 1):

```
   - (IBAction)previewDocument:(id)sender {
    NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"];

    if (URL) {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

        // Preview PDF
        [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: check that link it can help you

Comment: check the link for  more  references http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it may help to solve your problem.

```
NSURL* url = //...Your URL //[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
docController.delegate = self;
[docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't want to open preview @angel... I  just want to open mail composer from option menu....

Answer (score 0):

for this you can check the iOS version if it's < 8 then open that pdf file in web browser like this

```
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfFileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webview loadRequest:request];`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working fine for me

```
 @IBAction func btnPresentAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "backgroundPerson", ofType: "png")

        let urlI = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL!)

        let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: urlI)

        documentController.delegate = self

//        documentController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
        documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)

//        self.present(documentController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIView? {
        return self.view
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> CGRect {
        return self.view.frame
    }
```